# Trying to replace a string in the text file but not working

Tags: c#

```
class FunWithScheduling
{
        static void Main()
        {
                StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();
                string temp = "";
                string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(Scheduler.txt");
                foreach (string line in file)
                {
                            if (line.Contains("Subhadra"))
                            {
                                   temp = line.Replace("Subhadra", "Thangam");
                                   newFile.Append(temp + "\r\n");
                                   continue;
                             }
                             newFile.Append(line + "\r\n");
                }
                File.WriteAllText("Scheduler.txt", newFile.ToString());
            }
         }
```

Comment: **How** is it not working?

Comment: Can you put a little more effort in please? Like, describe your problem in more detail than "but not working"?

Comment: CS1010 Newline in constant. At the for each

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the opening quote in the following line:

```
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(Scheduler.txt");
```

As such, the compiler is reading everything **after** that ending quote as the start of a string constant.

In order to fix this, you need to change the above line to the below, which has the opening quote:-

```
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines("Scheduler.txt");
```

Comment: @user2665618:  You're missing the first quote.

Comment: @user2665618:- Replace string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(Scheduler.txt"); with the one that I have answered!! :)

Comment: I really don't get this

Comment: @user2665618 look at my edit - your code is missing a `"`.

Comment: @RahulTripathi I couldn't also see the difference between the line in question and in your answer till  Blorgbeard's comment. This is why you got a -1

Comment: Sir I was the first to spot the change. Well Blorgbeard's comment was just an addition to my answer!!! :(

Comment: @RahulTripathi I know, you just could have explained a little bit. As i said, I scrolled up and down and didn't see any difference till that comment.

Comment: @I4V:- I got your point Sir but I dont think that I deserve your downvote. I would have definitely added to my answer even if he has not commeneted. Anyways no hard feelings but I really dont deserve your downvote :(

Comment: @I4V:- And yes I would definitely keep that in mind in future so that I dont get a downvote for a right answer!!! ;)

Comment: @RahulTripathi 4 upvotes and one downvote still gets you +38 rep, I wouldn't worry about it :)

Comment: Although actually, this question may well be deleted in future, and you'll lose it all anyway!